# Mixin that uses component properties (Vue 2, TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mixin

I have `Vue` + `TypeScript` project, we are using `Vue class components`. One of component's methods was moved to separate mixin. That mixin uses component's properties. To prevent `TypeScript`'s complaining about missing in mixin properties I created interface with the same name as mixin has:

```
export interface ExpSelectedHandlerMixin {
  loading: boolean;
  selected: VouchersPoolTable[];
  currentApplication: string;
  items: VouchersPoolTable[];
}

@Component({})
export class ExpSelectedHandlerMixin extends Vue {
   // ...
}
```

Then connected mixin to my component like that:

```
import { Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class PageVouchersTable extends Mixins(ExpSelectedHandlerMixin) {
   // ...
}
```

After that I get error with the text:

*Class 'PageVouchersTable' incorrectly extends base class 'ExpSelectedHandlerMixin & Vue & object & Record<never, any>'.
Type 'PageVouchersTable' is not assignable to type 'ExpSelectedHandlerMixin'.
Property 'loading' is private in type 'PageVouchersTable' but not in type 'ExpSelectedHandlerMixin'.*

Ok, I made `loading`, `selected`, `currentApplication`, `items` properties in component `public` (simply deleted `private` modifier).

That works.

**BUT:**

Is it possible somehow to connect mixin that uses component's properties without making those properties `public`?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to get rid of unnecessary interface declaration in the mixin file and leave shared properties as `public` in the component. Final version of code is:

```
// Mixin
@Component({})
export default class ExpSelectedHandlerMixin extends Vue {
  loading = false

  items: VouchersPoolTable[] = []

  selected: VouchersPoolTable[] = []

  // ...
}

// Component
import { Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class PageVouchersTable extends Mixins(ExpSelectedHandlerMixin) {

  // Next three properties are public to be accessible in ExpSelectedHandlerMixin
  loading = false

  items: VouchersPoolTable[] = []

  selected: VouchersPoolTable[] = []

  // ...
}
```